# Language files inside a plugin in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

[This document](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1%3aCreating_a_content_plugin) says "Plugin language files are always installed in administrator/languages/xx-XX/....." However I tried including language files inside my plugin at `plugins/content/plugin_test/language/en-GB/....` and inside my `plugin_test.php` file, I've added the following code:

```
function __construct(& $subject, $config) {
    $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $lang->load('plg_content_plugin_test', dirname(__FILE__));
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);

}
```

This seems to work fine. I was wondering if this is a correct approach to include the language files or the language files must be placed inside the `administrator` folder as suggested in the docs?

Comment: This is absolutely fine to have the translation language files in your plugin folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in fact [it's recommended](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#Language_files).

That document was out of date, since Joomla 1.6 the recommended location has been for language files to be stored within the extension's directory. This is explained in the [Language section](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#Language_files) of the [Manifest Files](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files) article.

I've update the [J3.2 Creating a content plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aCreating_a_content_plugin) article to reflect the [Manifest Files](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files) article.